# Perl Module Installation

Tags: perl, perl-module

I am attempting to install a Perl Module entitled: File-Copy-Recursive and I am following these steps:

1) open cmd.exe
2) perl -MCPAN -e 'install File::Copy::Recursive;'

and I receive the message "It looks like you don't have a C compiler and make utility installed. Trying to install dmake and the MinGW gcc compiler using the Perl Package Manager. This may take a few minutes..."

"Downloading ActiveState Package Repository packlist...failed 500 Can't connect to ppm4.activestate.com:80 (connect: timeout).
Downloading File-Copy-Recursive packlist...not found
ppm.bat install failed: Can't find any package that provides MinGW"

These failed because I am behind a proxy, and I do know the proxy settings but I don't know how to apply them in this situation.

Is anyone aware of any alternative fixes to this solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems you are using ActiveState Perl, which comes with its own package manager (called PPM) to ease the pain of installing modules, especially those which would normally require a C compiler to be able to install.

Try following the [instructions](http://docs.activestate.com/activeperl/5.10/faq/ActivePerl-faq2.html#ppm_and_proxies) to set up your environment so that PPM knows about your proxy. For example, to set the proxy settings for a single instance of `cmd.exe`:

```
C:\>set http_proxy=http://username:password@proxy.example.org:8080
```

Then, in the same command prompt window, try this (it works for me, though I'm not behind a proxy):

```
C:\>ppm install File-Copy-Recursive
```

Note that it's probably a good idea (maybe even required?) to run `cmd.exe` "As Administrator" to make sure it has full authorization.

**EDIT:** The particular module you want to use is written in pure Perl. For a quick "installation", you can just download it from CPAN, extract the files, and copy the "Recursive.pm" file into a File\Copy directory structure placed in the same directory as your script:

```
yourscript.pl
File\
    Copy\
        Recursive.pm
```

Comment: Thanks!!!! This solved it, it was either running cmd as admin and/or set http_proxy=http://username:password@proxy.example.org:8080. Thanks.

Comment: @Christopher: Great, glad to have helped :-) I'd appreciate if you could mark this answer as "accepted" (by clicking the green check-mark outline under the vote count)

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative you could try the [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/) distribution which comes with tools for building XS modules.

Comment: +1. Might be too much trouble for the OP (if there's lots of non-core modules which would need to be installed again), but installing modules under Strawberry Perl is _so much_ easier :D

Answer (score 1):

Hi
I guess you are using Activestate Perl

look at 
http://docs.activestate.com/activeperl/5.10/faq/ActivePerl-faq2.html#what_is_ppm

PPM is installed automatically with ActivePerl.

To use PPM, your computer must be connected to the internet, have access to a PPM repository on a local hard drive or network share, or have access to a mounted ActiveState ActiveDVD.

If you connect to the internet via firewall or proxy, you may need to set the http_proxy environment variable. See PPM, Proxies and Firewalls for more information.